# how do i convert 2D image to 3D image like PopPic 3d app in swift 5

Tags: ios, animation, 3d, swift5, motion

I want this kind of functionality in my app. this app converts captured image to. 3d image. and also have functionality to convert. 3d to video. please let me know how do i achieve this in my swift app.

Comment: https://poppic.cam/ check this. link for more detail

Answer (score -1):

You can use online websites like
1 [Aspose](https://products.aspose.app/3d/conversion/jpg-to-3ds)
2. [Picto3d](https://picto3d.com/)
Etc. Or just google image to 3d converter online. Its easy bro.

Comment: i want to code this functionality in swift language ...

Comment: anyone found the solution?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).